# separating strings and numbers in text file

Tags: python

I have a file which has numbers as well strings in it, the file looks like:

## example.txt

```
100
no of benches = 40
no of lights=160
400
700
```

i tried using `string.atoi` to separate the numbers but i failed to get the output. this was my code:

```
import string
file = open('sample.txt')
numbers = file.readline()
k= string.atoi(numbers)
print(k)
```

Is there any specific module or command to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be easily retreived by the regular expressions

```
import string
import re
file = open('sample.txt')
numbers = [[int(num) for num in re.findall(r'\d+', i)] for i in file.readlines()]
#output [[100], [40], [160], [400], [700]]
```

Comment: natraj i tried the code it works but i need the numbers as int data type not as str and the output of the code comes into a list and when i do data type conversion there is an error... can you just help with that